# Perform action button in uitableview cell to perform delete functionality

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have one table view, and in each cell i have `X` Button for delete the particular cell . So i have done the iboutlet of the button to my custom table view cell. And in my cell row at index path i have done the add target to my button. But when i press my button in my table view cell. App crash. If i put the braekpoint. Its showing in the target added code line.

Here my code :

```
func followButton(sender: AnyObject) {


        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            print("Button Clicked: \(button.tag)")
            let item = Addtocartdata[button.tag]
            print("name: \(item.cartid!)")

            let headers = [
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                "postman-token": "4c933910-0da0-b199-257b-28fb0b5a89ec"
            ]

            let jsonObj:Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                "cartID" : "\(item.cartid!)",
                "cartType" : "3"
            ]


            if (!JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObj)) {
                print("is not a valid json object")
                return
            }

            if let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObj, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) {
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://exp.Cart.php")! as URL,
                                                  cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
                request.httpBody = postData

                let session = URLSession.shared
                let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        ///print(error)
                    } else {

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                            if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                            {
                                let status = json["status"] as? Int;

                                if(status == 1)
                                {

                                    // self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    print("items deleted")
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                                }

                            }
                        })
                    }
                })

                dataTask.resume()
            }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3, `action`'s argument is a selector, the syntax is `#selector(method-signature)`. So the final code is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartcel", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCell
    cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(followButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell;
}
```

For your additional question:

> I need to get the value of each cell and i need to pass as a parameter
>   to one api call. So if it does not mach. Then how can i do the
>   selector. To perform the delete functionality

```
func followButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        print("Button Clicked: \(button.tag)")
        let item = Addtocartdata[button.tag]
        print("name: \(item.cartproName), quality: \(item.proqty), price: \(item.cartproPrice)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code as an answer. A good answer explains what was wrong and also explains how the answer fixes the problem.

Comment: @Danh Huyng  i am getting the index path.Thats fine. But how can i get the partcular cell values ??

Comment: say like, i have name, price, qty for each cell. When ever i press any cell `X` Button. How can i get the values of that particular cell values

Comment: Do you have any arrays contain these things? The data that you fill the tableView

Comment: yes, see my updated post. I have one seperate class called `Addtocartdata`

Comment: I edited my answer! You have indexPath, so just retrieve item at indexPath of `Addtocartdata` and send its values to your server.

Comment: Yes, i have done. But one i delet any cell. I am doing the table view reload. But still my data are there. If i navigate to another screen. And if i come back to my screen.My items are deleted. Please see my updated post. And please help me out.This alone

Comment: Let remove item at indexPath before call `tableView.reloadData()`, `Addtocartdata.remove(at: button.tag)`

Answer (score 2):

To add a selector from swift2.2 or higher the syntax is changed, you have to add target like this

```
cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(followButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

This is how you will get indexpath of that cell, with the indexpath you can do the rest

```
func followButton(sender: UIButton!) {
    let point : CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:collectionView)
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point)
    // here is your index path
}
```

Comment: OK..will check it out. But can you please tell me, how can i get the details of each cell values . Like in my cell i have name,amount,qty. So i need to pass these parameters to my api call to perform the delete functionality. So when ever i press any cell button. How can i get that particular cell details or value ??

Comment: This selector is incorrect. It doesn't account for the parameter on the `followButton(sender:)` function.

Comment: @rmaddy  i din get you. I need to get the value of each cell and i need to pass as a parameter to one api call. So if it does not mach. Then how can i do the selector. To perform the delete functionality